# How to filter queryset in changelist_view in django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-queryset, changelist

Let's say I have a site where Users can add Entries through admin panel. Each User has his own Category he is responsible for (each Category has an Editor assigned through ForeingKey/ManyToManyField).

When User adds Entry, I limit the choices by using EntryAdmin like this:

```
class EntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    (...)

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'category':
            if request.user.is_superuser:
                kwargs['queryset'] = Category.objects.all()
            else:
                kwargs['queryset'] = Category.objects.filter(editors=request.user)
            return db_field.formfield(**kwargs)
        return super(EntryAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

This way I can limit the categories to which a User can add Entry and it works perfect.

Now the tricky part: On the Entry changelist/action page I want to show only those Entries which belong to current User's Category. I tried to do this using this method:

```
    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            self.queryset = self.queryset.filter(editors=request.user)
```

But I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'filter'

This is strange, because I thought it should be a typical QuerySet. Basically such methods are [not well documented](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.changelist_view) and digging through tons of Django code is not my favourite sport.

Any ideas how can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Warning: This answer is from 2010, and is not useful for Django >= 1.8.**

`queryset` is a method on `ModelAdmin` which returns a queryset. You need to override it on your `EntryAdmin` class.

```
def queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(EntryAdmin, self).queryset(request)
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return qs
    else:
        return qs.filter(editors=request.user)
```

Changing the queryset will limit the Entries shown in the list view. You also need to override `has_change_permission` to ensure that the user has permission to edit the object on the individual object editing page. See the following blog post by James Bennett for further details:

http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/dec/24/admin/

Comment: The QuerySet needs to be filtered by Category. But there's a problem when User has more than one Category assigned. Or maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: At least in Django 2.2, the method is called `get_queryset` and not `queryset`.

Comment: @ge0rg Yes, the methods were [renamed in Django 1.6](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.6/#get-query-set-and-similar-methods-renamed-to-get-queryset). The question and answer are nearly 10 years old, so they are not very useful for modern versions of Django.

Comment: The example in the latest Django (3.0) documentation looks pretty much the same, apart from the method name: [ModelAdmin.get_queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset). So I guess at least that part of the answer still *is* useful?